# Sync incompatible role error message in MongoDB App Services even though sync seems to work

Tags: database, mongodb, permissions, realm

I have a *Flexible Sync* app in MongoDB App Services (formerly *MongoDB Realm*).

The main model object is an `Activity`, which should be readable and writable by its *owner*, but also read-only by a *supervisor*.

These are the sync roles I have set up:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Activity": [
      {
        "name": "owner_supervisor_activity_permission",
        "applyWhen": {},
        "read": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "ownerID": "%%user.id"
            },
            {
              "supervisorID": "%%user.id"
            }
          ]
        },
        "write": {
          "ownerID": "%%user.id"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "defaultRoles": [
    {
      "name": "owner-read-write",
      "applyWhen": {},
      "read": {
        "ownerID": "%%user.id"
      },
      "write": {
        "ownerID": "%%user.id"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Although sync seems to work just fine, I get the following error message in the logs for both roles:

> Using sync incompatible role "owner_supervisor_activity_permission" for table "Activity". this role will default to deny all access. consider changing this role to be sync compatible (ProtocolErrorCode=201)

I do not know what to do here and I’m wondering if it could be a bug.

Do I need to set the per-collection rules? I thought sync roles overrode those.

Is it a matter of using the `applyWhen` field?

Thanks

Comment: Did you define the "owner_supervisor_activity_permission" in the UI or CLI? I don't see it referenced anywhere else in the question.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your response. It’s defined in the UI, exactly as written (at the bottom of the Sync screen). I’m not sure if I need to reference it elsewhere?

Comment: @Jay Because any user (owner) might also be someone else’s supervisor, and users can only have one session role, I needed to make a role that covers both eventualities.

Comment: I believe that's actually a bug that has been identified. Please see [sync incompatible role](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/sync-compatible-rows/197884) in the Realm forums.

Comment: @Jay Thanks! I see MongoDB have acknowledged the bug, which is encouraging.

Comment: @Jay I’m happy to accept and upvote if you want to add that as an answer btw.